# C# Dynamically set a ServerReport report paramter

Tags: c#, webforms, report

How do you dynamically set a ServerReport (Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport) parameter that has dependencies in order to populate the list of another parameter? I am retrieving the parameters directly from the rdl, but some parameters have dependencies and won't populate a list unless the dependency is solved.

```
ServerReport serverReport = new ServerReport();
serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("localhost/testserverreport");
serverReport.ReportPath = "test/test report";

var parameters = serverReport.GetParameters();
```

Comment: Just set the value, or are you asking how to detect the dependent properties that need to be set?

Comment: That won't work. Parameters is a ReportParameterInfoCollection collection.  Each paramter is a ReportParameterInfo object. This contains a field values which is the values that is being selected. I am using aspx to display the parameters in a DataGrid, which a dropdownlist for each parameter using the ValidValues field of the ReportParameterInfo object. For example if parameter x has a dependency on y, when x gets selected in the UI, the list for parameter y should automatically be populated.

Comment: But my question is do you _know_ the parameters or are you trying to "sniff" them out? Setting the parameter value is generally the easy bit once you know which parameters need to be set.

Comment: No I do not know the parameters before retrieving them from the rdl using serverReport.GetParameters(), but I do keep a record of the parameter name so quite easy to retrieve the entire parameter, with it's dependent. My problem is how do you set the parameter value using a generic method that will work on any given rdl that has dependents on a parameter. Easy solution would be to set a default value on the rdl's parameter and this will resolve the need for all of that, but not very efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach is to iterate through the parameter collection and inspect the `.Dependents` for each parameter.

If you already know the parameters, either through inspection of the RDL or through your own application configuration, then you can use `SetParameters()` to send the values to the server-side report:

```
ServerReport serverReport = new ServerReport();
serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("localhost/testserverreport");
serverReport.ReportPath = "test/test report";

var parameterInfos = serverReport.GetParameters();

... resolve your parameter values

List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
var parameter1 = new ReportParameter();
parameter1.Name = "parametername"; // get the name from parameterInfos 
parameter1.Values.Add("1"); // your value here

serverReport.SetParameters(parameters.ToArray());
```

The only strangeness to this type of code is that I would normally set the server report through the report viewer control, and not instantiate the `ServerReport` directly, which might be where you are going wrong

```
reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;

reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:portno/ReportServer"); // Report Server URL
reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "test/test report"; // Report Name

List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
var parameter1 = new ReportParameter();
parameter1.Name = "parametername"; // get the name from parameterInfos 
parameter1.Values.Add("1"); // your value here

reportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(parameters.ToArray());
```

If you are not using the report viewer control at all, but you are till expecting to render server-side, then you can pass the parameters via url parameters instead of directly through the `ServerReport` at all.